# Multiple Recaptcha Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, recaptcha

I have multiple form on website integrated with *reCAPTCHA* . Two registration form for two types of users and one contact form.

In header reCAPTCHA API is added like this.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

In footer i added reCAPTCHA render functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        //alert(response);
      };

      var widgetId1;
      var widgetId2;
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        // Renders the HTML element with id 'example1' as a reCAPTCHA widget.
        // The id of the reCAPTCHA widget is assigned to 'widgetId1'.

        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('hiddenRecaptcha1', {
          'sitekey' : 'sitekey',
          'theme' : 'light',
          'callback' : verifyCallback,
        });

        widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('hiddenRecaptcha2'), {
          'sitekey' : 'sitekey',
          'callback' : verifyCallback
        });
        grecaptcha.render('hiddenRecaptcha', {
          'sitekey' : 'sitekey',
          'callback' : verifyCallback,
          'theme' : 'dark'
        });
      };
</script>
```

I am validating all reCAPTCHA with jquery.

**Contact Form Validation**

```
$("#contactus").validate({
ignore: ":hidden:not(.my_cpa)",
rules: {
    "hiddenRecaptcha": {
        required: function() {
            if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
},
messages: {
    "hiddenRecaptcha": "Please Prove That You Are Not Robot"
},
highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).removeClass('has-error');
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
});
```

**Captcha in Contact Form**

```
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div id="hiddenRecaptcha"></div>
        <input type="hidden" class="my_cpa hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
</div>
```

**Captcha in First Registration Form and its validation**

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div id="hiddenRecaptcha1"></div>
    <input type="hidden" class="my_cpa1 hiddenRecaptcha1 required" name="hiddenRecaptcha1" id="hiddenRecaptcha1">
</div>


function residentForm(){
        var settings = $('#registration_form').validate().settings;
        $.extend(settings, {
            ignore: ":hidden:not(.my_cpa1)",
            rules: {
                "hiddenRecaptcha1": {
                    required: function() {
                        if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "hiddenRecaptcha1": "Please Prove That You Are Not Robot"
            }
        });
    }
```

**Captcha in Second Registration Form and its validation**

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div id="hiddenRecaptcha2"></div>
        <input type="hidden" class="my_cpa2 hiddenRecaptcha2 required" name="hiddenRecaptcha2" id="hiddenRecaptcha2">
</div>

function businessForm(){
        var settings = $('#bregistration_form').validate().settings;
        $.extend(settings, {
            ignore: ":hidden:not(.my_cpa2)",
            rules: {
                "hiddenRecaptcha2": {
                    required: function() {
                        if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "hiddenRecaptcha2": "Please Prove That You Are Not Robot"
            }
        });
    }
```

**Problem:**

Only First Registration form Validated using jquery and submitting successfully, while on other form it still showing message that *Please Prove That You Are Not Robot* and form is not submitting.

When i am on any page *other than contact page*, it showing following message in console.

> reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id

I have check all these answers, [ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014160/recaptcha-placeholder-element-must-be-an-element-or-id) , [Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132750/uncaught-error-recaptcha-placeholder-element-must-be-an-element-or-id) and [ReCaptcha: “The bind parameter must be an element or id”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657573/recaptcha-the-bind-parameter-must-be-an-element-or-id). but can't validate my form and can't remove error.

**Anybody can tell me where i am doing wrong?**

Comment: "When i am on any page other than contact page, it showing following message in console."

>>> You might have accidentally included the reCAPTCHA  JS codes in all of your pages.

Comment: Login and registration form are in MODAL, so modal should appear on all pages, so i add the js file in footer.

Comment: Do the login and registration modals appear in many pages?

Comment: yeah, on all pages,

Comment: Does the Contact Form appear on all pages too?
The JS for it seems to be included with the JS for login and registration.